# MySQL record between fixed date range

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, date, datetime, codeigniter-3

I have an small application which was build with CodeIgniter 3 and need to perform a report which will be converted to Chart.js. The report should be in yearly basis but at given specific date every month. The requirement are all data count must be from 4th to 3rd monthly. Like this:

For example January Report would be from 4th January to 3rd February, 4th February to 3rd March,... and so on.

I have created a MySQL query but I'm stuck on how to get the date too date. My Query are as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created, '%Y') as 'year',
DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created, '%m') as 'month',
COUNT(odd_id) as 'total', status
FROM odd_data 
WHERE status = $id and 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created, '%Y%m'), status
```

I'm new to MySQl. Could somebody help me on this. I'm stuck where should I put the date to date query.

Comment: Sometimes its easier to work with date spans/ranges as a unix timestamp. MySQL has `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` if your fields are a datetime. And then PHP easily makes timestamps from specific dates using `mktime`.

Comment: Stricly within mysql you're not going to be able to easily parcel out the dates if they don't neatly lie on the month boundaries. You're probably best off issuing 12 queries with `WHERE date_field BETWEEN '2017-11-03' AND '2017-12-03'` and then combining the results in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I want to caution you not to use "between" with the following when you come to join your data, use this method instead `data.date >= r.period_start_dt and data.date < r.period_end_dt`

Secondly I am assuming your data does have dates or timestamps and that will fall between the calculated ranges that follow:

```
set @year :=2017;

select
       *
from (
        select 
               start_dt + INTERVAL m.n MONTH     period_start_dt
             , start_dt + INTERVAL m.n + 1 MONTH period_end_dt
        from (
               select str_to_date(concat(@year,'-01-04'),'%Y-%m-%d') start_dt ) seed
        cross join (select 0 n union all
                    select 1 union all
                    select 2 union all
                    select 3 union all
                    select 4 union all
                    select 5 union all
                    select 6 union all
                    select 7 union all
                    select 8 union all
                    select 9 union all
                    select 10 union all
                    select 11
                   ) m
     ) r
## LEFT JOIN YOUR DATA
## ON data.date >= r.period_start_dt and data.date < r.period_end_dt
```

Example ranges: (produce you own at this demo: http://rextester.com/CHTKSA95303 )

```
nb dd.mm.yyyy (.de format)
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|    |   period_start_dt   |    period_end_dt    |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 04.01.2017 00:00:00 | 04.02.2017 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 04.02.2017 00:00:00 | 04.03.2017 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 04.03.2017 00:00:00 | 04.04.2017 00:00:00 |
|  4 | 04.04.2017 00:00:00 | 04.05.2017 00:00:00 |
|  5 | 04.05.2017 00:00:00 | 04.06.2017 00:00:00 |
|  6 | 04.06.2017 00:00:00 | 04.07.2017 00:00:00 |
|  7 | 04.07.2017 00:00:00 | 04.08.2017 00:00:00 |
|  8 | 04.08.2017 00:00:00 | 04.09.2017 00:00:00 |
|  9 | 04.09.2017 00:00:00 | 04.10.2017 00:00:00 |
| 10 | 04.10.2017 00:00:00 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 | 04.12.2017 00:00:00 |
| 12 | 04.12.2017 00:00:00 | 04.01.2018 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the specification,  I think I would tempted to cheat it... subtract 3 days from the date.  Doing that, Jan 4 backs up to Jan 1,  Feb 3 backs up to Jan 31...   so those all end up as January.

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%Y') AS `year`
       , DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%m') AS `month`
       , ...
    FROM ...

   GROUP
      BY DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%Y')
       , DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%m')
```

This falls apart if there's oddball ranges...  if it's not always the 4th and 3rd.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it's working fine but now my client requested it to be able to filter according to year. how can I go about this.

Comment: The requirement "filter according to year" is vague as a specification. Providing example data and expected is a good way to illustrate the spec. Absent that, we're just guessing. Maybe what we're after is just adding `HAVING DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY,'%Y') = '2017'`.

Comment: or maybe we want to add conditions to the WHERE clause to restrict the rows ...  `AND odd_date_created >= '2017-01-03' AND odd_date_created < '2018-01-03'`.   We could use expressions in place of the literal values. `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-03') + INTERVAL -12 MONTH`

Comment: It works. Your my saviour. Really appreciate. Thanks @spencer7593

Comment: The first option adding "HAVING" condition, this is what I'm looking for.